# How do i make Laravel "remember" what the user last selected in a drop down menu?

Tags: php, forms, laravel, drop-down-menu

I'm building a filtering feature in an app that will filter out data (on the same page) with the inputs from two drop down menus. I want the drop downs to "remember" what the user selected and keep them as defaults.

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'GET', 'route' => ['path_filter_index']]) !!}

  {!! Form::select('user', [-1 => 'All'] + $users , $users) !!}
  {!! Form::select('customer', [-1 => 'All'] + $customers, $customers) !!}

  {!! Form::hidden('status', 0) !!}
  {!! Form::checkbox('status', 1) !!}

  {!! Form::submit('Filtrera', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm']) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres's a session based solution...
In your controller, the one that receives the data on submit:

```
Session::put('filter.user', Input::get('user'));
Session::put('filter.customer', Input::get('customer'));
```

Then in the your view

```
{!! Form::select('user', [-1 => 'All'] + $users , Session::get('filter.user')) !!}
{!! Form::select('customer', [-1 => 'All'] + $customers, Session::get('filter.customer')) !!}
```

Instead of retrieving the session values in the view you could also do that in your controller action and then pass them into the view